# cakephp manual sql query in one table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have this table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `realname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bos1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailbos1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

I got an issue here :

Two persons (eg: username=steve, and balmer) has bos1 name (eg: bill)
When I login as steve and/or balmer I can see my own detail / data,
but when I login as bill, I want to show steve's and balmer's detail as well.

How do i suppose to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have relations defined in your model?

Comment: nevermind, i jus got a clue :) thanks anyway osterhase

Comment: Please post your solution if other users have the same question.